# How to feed input into one layer in a tensorflow pre-trained model?

Tags: tensorflow

The pretrained model has many layers, I want to feed my input directly into one intermediate layer (and discard the result of the previous layers).
I only got the .pb file and the ckpt files of that model, so how to modify the computation flow without the source code?

This is the only code file that I got, but I dont know how to use it. Is the graph generate by this file?(much different from the normal tensorflow files)https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/models/ssd_mobilenet_v2_feature_extractor.py

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do :

- Load the model
- Find the name of the layer or retrieve the tensor of the layer you want to feed values to (let's name it 'Z' for the sake of the explanation)
- Find the name of the layer or retrieve the tensor of the layer you want to get results from ('Y')
- Run this code snippet :`results = sess.run('Y:0', {'Z:0': your_value})`